# How to make Realm query with subquery and in statement

Tags: java, android, sql, realm

I'm now working Realm with java, I have no idea how can I use subquery.

I have two RealmObjects like below.

```java
public class Sms extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String address;
}
public class Statement extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String smsId;
}
```

And I want query with Realm to do same work like sql below.

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    sms
WHERE
    id not in (
        SELECT
            sms_id
        FROM
            statement
    )
    and address = "123456789"
;
```

How can I achieve it?

---

Update 2015-12-18 :

@geisshirt, many thanks for answer kindly.

I had a idea from his answer, and below is result.

```
RealmResults<Statement> statements = realm.where(Statement.class).findAll();
RealmQuery<Sms> query = realm.where(Sms.class).equalTo("address", "123456789");
for(Statement statement : statements){
    query = query.notEqualTo("id", statement.getSmsId());
}
RealmResults<Sms> smsList = query.findAll();
```

I think this will achieve my goal, but I'm doubtful about this is the only way to achieve `not in` or `in` statement.

Is there noway to do this more clearly?

Comment: The loop, you're using above, is currently the only way to do something like `in`. See also https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/841

Comment: @geisshirt thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

With your current model, you will have to iterate:

```
RealmResults<Statement> statements = realm.where(Statement.class).equalTo("address", "123456789").findAll();
for(Statement statement : statements) {
    RealmResults<Sms> sms = realm.where(Sms.class).notEqualTo("id", statement.smsId).findAll();
    // do something to sms
}
```

I'm not sure what the query really means: did you mean `id in` instead of `id not in`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for kindly answer my question. I was mean `id not in`. I'm not sure but I think your code makes lots of `SELECT
    *
FROM
    sms
WHERE
    id != "example_sms_id"
    and address = "123456789"
;`... isn't it? Thanks again for answer. @geisshirt